# how to convert a range to its median in pandas csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset (CSV file) that contains numerical values and range values in the same column
as example i have:
name  age
Sara   18
Jhon    18-20
how can I transform the age column to be the same for both entries?
output as exemple
name  age
Sara   18
Jhon    19=18+20/2
thanks
this is an update on my question :
[image]

as you can see my dataframecontains two columns  one is heat of formation in which there are range values and numerical values,same thing for the pressure where there are numerical values linked to a string,i need to convert these values to floats for the training of a model.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the following method:

```
a = pd.Series(['46-55','12', '26-35', '60+'])
b = a.str.findall('(\d+)')
c = pd.Series([])
for i in range(0,len(b)):
    b[i] = np.array(b[i]).astype(np.float)
    c[i] = sum(b[i]) / len(b[i])
```

The first step is to change the range elements to individual:

```
b = a.str.findall('(\d+)')
print(b)
```

which returns:

```
0    [46, 55]
1        [12]
2    [26, 35]
3        [60]
dtype: object
```

In the second, define a series to which you append the mean of the arrays in `b` in the following way:

```
for i in range(0,len(b)):
    b[i] = np.array(b[i]).astype(np.float)
    c[i] = sum(b[i]) / len(b[i])
```

which gives:

```
0   50.50
1   12.00
2   30.50
3   60.00
dtype: float64
```

For a dataframe it would go like this:

```
df
Name     Age
0  sarah      19
1   john   15-20
```

and

```
df['b'] =df[' Age'].str.findall('(\d+)')
df['b_float'] =df['b'].apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x))
df['Mean'] = [np.array(x).mean() for x in df['b_float']]
```

which gives:

```
    Name     Age         b   b_float  Mean
0  sarah      19      [19]      [19] 19.00
1   john   15-20  [15, 20]  [15, 20] 17.50
```

Comment: hello serge,thanks for your answer,however when i did that i get this error in parsing the first data  :ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "71 - 80"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 thanks

Comment: Try to replace ```pd.to_numeric(x)``` with ```pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')```

Comment: Do this: Update your question by adding a sample of your own data. Eg. Post the result of ```df.head(10).to_dict()``` . It will make it easier to trace back the error.